# chrome extension context menu not showing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

chrome extension context menu not showing up, just in current debug profile, even log out, and create a new profile and login the same account. But, It works in another profile.

Use `chrome.contextMenus.create({contexts:["all"],title:"test"})` run at background, also, not showing up.